# Cursor Placement and "Smart Semicolons" in MonoDevelop

Tags: ide, monodevelop

i'm trying to get MonoDevelop to a less obnoxious state. i'm coming from FlashDevelop, which is *like buttah*.

In MD, i've checked the option to "Insert matching brace", but it kills me that the caret/cursor is placed between the resulting braces instead of at the end of them:

```
DoStuff(|)
```

(where | is my cursor) Since i'm constantly forgetting brackets, i like to set up all of my braces ahead of time, and fill in the content later.  So i'll often type

```
function DoStuff()
{
}|
```

all in one go. Ideally, the IDE will close my round brace and then the curly one, and my cursor will wind up after that final curly brace.  But with MonoDevelop, i wind up with the cursor inside the round braces as soon as i type them.  It's aggravating.

Is there a way to force MD to place the cursor after the closing brace (other than turning this feature off and manually typing both braces)?

Also, i have "Smart semicolon placement" checked.  If i type

```
DoStuff()
```

i'd expect a semicolon to be automatically placed at the end of that line.  But it's not. Not so smart, if you ask me.  Where are these clever semicolons supposed to appear?

Comment: Are you using Java or C# here?

Comment: Doesn't really matter - the feature is going to (mis)behave regardless of which language i'm using.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry I can't help much further on this. Although this doesn't answer your question, you may want to consider using Visual Studio for your Unity3D project - Its the best C# IDE available.

Answer (score 1):

If you enabled 'Smart semicolon placement' just type it inside the braces and the semicolon will jump to the end of the line automatically.
So you would type `DoStuff(;` and get `DoStuff();`
Tested in MonoDevelop 4.0.1 on a Mac.